# How To Press Save on Internet Explorer Popup?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I manipulate the below Internet Explorer download popup.
[image: pic]

I tried the below code, but this is not a frame notification bar, so it doesn't help.

```
Sub PressSave(ie As InternetExplorer)
    Dim o As IUIAutomation
    Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 4))
    Set o = New CUIAutomation
    Dim h As Long
    h = ie.hwnd
    'find notification bar
    h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
    If h = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    'find save button
    Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
    Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
    Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
    Do Until Not Button Is Nothing
        Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")
        Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
    Loop
    
    'click save
    Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
    Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
    InvokePattern.Invoke
    
    'wait till file is completely downloaded
    Dim iOpen As IUIAutomationCondition
    Dim OpenButton As IUIAutomationElement
    Do Until Not OpenButton Is Nothing
        Set iOpen = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "View 
downloads")
        Set OpenButton = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iOpen)
    Loop
End Sub
```

I tried using an API to get the data but kept getting error 401, which means it requires authentication, and I'm not sure if I can add arguments to give that.

```
Sub APIToGetData()
Dim sURL As String
Dim savePath As String
Dim WinHttpReq As Object

savePath = "C:\Downloads"
sURL = "https://[myurlhere]/api/admin/data_dumps/download"
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

WinHttpReq.Open "GET", sURL, False
WinHttpReq.send

If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.Close
End If
End Sub
```

How do I manipulate this popup without using SendKeys?

Comment: Can you workaround this problem by using an API to download the file?

Comment: updated my question. Not sure if it makes a difference, but it's a group of files

Comment: If you are going the API route you'll need to review the documentation. Typically there is a web request you make first, which authenticates with the API, basically you get back a string which identifies you as an authorized user. Usually you have something like a username/password, or an API key. Once authenticated, you pass the authentication information (usually in the headers) into the subsequent calls to the service.

Comment: Checked, and I don't think I'll be able to use an API. A new key is generated each time.

Comment: Depending on the implementation, that might be expected. Can you share which API you are reviewing?

Comment: I'm not great with API terminology. What do you mean by which API?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186497/discussion-between-ryan-wildry-and-w-hit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tate Garringer's answer has the correct logic, but for some reason wouldn't work for me. I ended up finding something that worked, as well as a ton of helpful information at:
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/502298-need-help-regarding-ie-automation-using-vba-3.html

The below is the direct answer to my question:

```
'Find the Save As window, waiting a maximum of 10 seconds for it to appear
timeout = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
Do
    hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "Save As")
    DoEvents
    Sleep 300
Loop Until hwnd Or Now > timeout
```

Hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

A year back or so I had a similar problem which I was able to solve by implementing API's

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
```

And

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
```

Using the FindWindow API I implemented a sort of watch procedure

```
Do Until FindWindow(vbNullString, "Internet Explorer") > 0
    Sleep 100
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Once it found the window, I had it confirm the default selection (which was "Open" in my case) until the window disappeard

```
Do Until FindWindow(vbNullString, "Internet Explorer") = 0
    SendMessage FindWindow(vbNullString, "Internet Explorer"), WM_COMMAND, IDOK, 0
    Sleep 100
    DoEvents
Loop
```

SendMessage is great because it sends the command directly to the targeted hWnd versus SendKeys which just sends a specified keystroke to whatever is in focus.

Comment: when i degub.print FindWindow(vbNullString, "Internet Explorer"), it gives "11143362". So it's always greater than 0

Comment: It should only be > 0 if a window titled "Internet Explorer" is open.