# Using Excel to Automate Internet Explorer Form Filling, then Download Export

Tags: excel, vba, getelementsbyname

I am trying to create a script that opens a page, types a value in, clicks a button on the webpage that downloads a data export, then saves the download, and closes webpage

I have gotten most of it to work. But I cannot figure out how to get the script to select save when the download dialogue box pops open asking "Do you want to open or save..."

I tried the "Application.SendKeys but that does nothing.

It is important to note that the script opens a medium integrity version of internet explorer because that is the only was I could get the "GetElementsByName" function to work.  If instead I use CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", I can get the SendKeys function to work, but my GetElementsByName function errors out.

Any thoughts on what I can do? Below is my code

```
Sub GetDataExport()


    Dim ARNUM As String
    Dim x As Integer
    
    NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    
    x = 1
    
    For x = 1 To NumRows

    ARNUM = Range("A" & x)

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://qrwb.ecorp.cat.com/cpi/AnalysisTools/Analysis_Tools.cfm?tool=Arrangement"
    
    Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    
    
    IE.document.getElementsByName("arrangement_no")(0).Value = ARNUM
    
    IE.document.getElementsByName("Download")(0).Click
    
    Application.SendKeys ("%(s)")
    
    Application.SendKeys ("^(w)")
    
    Next x



End Sub
```

Comment: What format is the download?  Excel?   It's possible you could download it directly, but it depends on exactly what the "Download" element is and what it's hooked up to.

Comment: yes it outputs an .xls file. What to you mean download it directly? The download element is nothing fancy. I pasted the HTML code from the inspect element page below. 

<input type="submit" name="Download" value="Export to Excel" style="margin:5px 10px;">

Comment: Some suggestions here for disabling the pop-up: https://superuser.com/questions/246553/how-to-disable-file-download-popup-in-internet-explorer

Comment: I thought of that, unfortunately my work IT's security settings group policy doesn't allow me to change that. The option doesn't even show up.

Comment: Maybe try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178503/how-to-click-on-ie-download-dialog-box-i-e-open-save-save-as  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133068/how-to-press-save-on-internet-explorer-popup